# Efficiency of strncpy and code

Tags: c, strcmp, strcat, strncpy

I'm slowly learning and progressing through coding, so I was hoping someone could have a quick look at this function for me and tell me if it appears that I'm on the right track, how I could do it better or where I might be setting myself up for failure. I'm new to the world of C, so please take it easy on me - but be blunt and honest.

```
void test(char *username, char *password) {

    printf("Checking password for %s - pw: %s\n",username,password);
    char *query1 = "SELECT password FROM logins WHERE email = '";
    char *query2 = "' LIMIT 1";

    char *querystring = malloc(strlen(query1) + strlen(username) + strlen(query2) * sizeof(char));

    strncpy(querystring,query1,strlen(query1));
    strncat(querystring,username,strlen(username));
    strncat(querystring,query2,strlen(query2));

    printf("Query string: %s\n",querystring);

    mysql_query(mysql_con,querystring);
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(mysql_con);


    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    int num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);

    if (num_rows != 0) {

        MYSQL_ROW row;
        printf("Query returned %i results with %i fields\n",num_rows,num_fields);

        row = mysql_fetch_row(result);

        printf("Password returned: %s\n",row[0]);

        int comparison = strncmp(password, row[0], strlen(password));

        if (comparison == 0) {
            printf("Passwords match!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Passwords do NOT match!\n");
        }

    } else {
        printf("No such user... Password is invalid");
    }
    free(querystring);
}
```

At the moment, it is working... output:

```
Checking password for jhall@futuresouth.us - pw: 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
Query string: SELECT password FROM logins WHERE email = 'test@blah.com' LIMIT 1
Query returned 1 results with 1 fields
Password returned: 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
Passwords match!
```

called with:

```
test("test@blah.com","5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99");
```

I'm looking for input on how I could have worked with the strings better, or if there are any unforeseen issues with how I did this. I'm very new to working with data structures in C.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code-review (try http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: and I noticed I botched up the formatting of the if statement and final else statement... Sorry for that.

Comment: `strncpy` and `strncat` and `malloc` are being used incorrectly. If this code appears to work then it's rather coincidental

Comment: When you say incorrectly, could you please give some insight?

Comment: Remember [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.org/327).  It isn't immediately your major concern, but you must remember it whenever you get anywhere near production.

Comment: Remember to allocate 1 extra character for the '\0'. Also, you can store the length obtained by strlen and use memcpy (not really needed here, but it's better).

Comment: Your question title asks about efficiency when you seem to be actually be more concerned with correctness and style (which is probably the correct things to worry about before worrying efficiency).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth codereview is for working code... this code is not "working" by any reasonable definition of the word

Comment: @MattMcNabb: OP claimed it was "working", so I looked no further...

Answer (score 1):

Using `strncpy(target, source, strlen(source))` guarantees that the string in `target` is not null terminated.  If perchance `malloc()` returns zeroed memory, then it will seem to work, but once `malloc()` returns non-zeroed memory (previously allocated memory), things will go wrong.

The length argument to `strncat()` is just plain weird; it is the amount of space left in the target string after the current (null-terminated) data.  Your usage, quite apart from not having null-terminated strings to work on, does not protect against buffer overflow.

There really isn't a good use case for `strncat()` IMNSHO, and seldom a good case for `strncpy()`.  If you know how big everything is, you can use `memmove()` (or `memcpy()`) instead.  If you don't know how big everything is, you don't know whether it is safe to do the copy without truncation.

Your `malloc()` call is a bit peculiar too: it doesn't allocate enough space for the trailing null, and it only multiplies one of the three terms by `sizeof(char)`, which is inconsistent but otherwise harmless.  A lot of the time you will get away with the short allocation because `malloc()` rounds the size up, but all hell will break loose when you don't get away with.  A tool like [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) will report abuse of allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan's answer explains the problems with that part of the code.

To fix it you can use `snprintf` instead:

```
size_t space_needed = strlen(query1) + strlen(username) + strlen(query2) + 1;
char *querystring = malloc(space_needed + 1);
if ( !query_string )
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

snprintf(query_string, space_needed, "%s%s%s", query1, username, query2);
```

Then, even if you calculate the length wrong, at least you didnt get a buffer overflow.

To avoid the code duplication here there is a non-standard function [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) that you pass the arguments and it yields a pointer to a `malloc`'d buffer of the right size. Of course, it's possible to write your own version of this function if you don't want to rely on the existence of that function.

There's another serious issue here in that your code does not protect against SQL injection ([see here](http://xkcd.com/327/) for explanation). A proper discussion of how to protect against that is probably beyond the scope of this question!